# JavaScript event scrolling won't fire

Tags: javascript, html

I've had a look around although I can't find anything to solve the issue. I'm designing an image portfolio website and want to load images as they come into the viewport for performance reasons. Images that are initially in view load fine although no images load when they're scrolled in

```
<script>
    registerListener('load', lazyLoad);
    registerListener('scroll', lazyLoad);

    function isInViewport(elem) {
        var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (
            distance.top >= 0 &&
            distance.left >= 0 &&
            distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && distance.right <=(window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        ); 
    }; 

    var image = [];

    lazy = document.getElementsByClassName('lazy');
    console.log("there are  " + lazy.length + " lazy images")

    function lazyLoad() {
        for (i = 0; i < lazy.length; i++) {
            console.log('attempting to load' + (i+1));
            if (isInViewport(lazy[i])) {
                console.log("loaded: image " + (i+1));
                lazy[i].src = lazy[i].getAttribute('data-src');
            }            
        }
    }

    function registerListener(event, func) {
        window.addEventListener(event, func);
    }
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks (my first question on Stackoverflow so please let me know if I've done it wrong)

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The `lazyLoad` function should skip images that have already been loaded.

Comment: The problem is that I cant seem to get the scroll event to fire and run the `lazyLoad` function

Comment: I don't see any reason why the function wouldn't run. Put `console.log("scrolling")` in the `lazyLoad` function to see whether it's running.

Comment: I just tried your code and it was called.

Comment: It runs once on load and then no more

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/acm5ugb1/2/

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using the scroll event for lazy loading images anymore, nowadays there are better performing options available. 
The newest method (which for now only works in the newest chrome browser) is to use `<img src="pic.jpg" loading="lazy">` If you add the loading attribute to an img (or even an iframe) it will load once it is visible to the user. No JS needed for that.

The second best method for lazy loading images is to use the [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) With this you can define objects that the browser should watch and define an intersection with another object (or the whole window) and then react to whenever this intersection occurs.

First you have to define your observer:

```
var options = {
 threshold: 2.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

root defaults to browser viewport, which is what we need for image lazy loading.

Then define the targets for the observer:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.lazy-load');
observer.observe(target);
```

Last, define what should happen with the targets once they are visible:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
  // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
  });
};
```

All example code is taken from mozillas developer documentation, see the page for more details and even more examples.